# How to add X(Close button) in v-autocomplete vuetify?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vuex, vuejs3

how can I add close button inside v-autocomplete list, so I could be able to close it using the button which is inside it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#usage)

```
<v-autocomplete
  chips <-- added because it looks cool
  clearable <-- x button for clear all input
  deletable-chips <-- this add x button for input
  multiple <-- you can select multiple 
></v-autocomplete>
```

Try this

```
<v-autocomplete
  chips
  clearable
  deletable-chips
  multiple
  small-chips
></v-autocomplete>
```

it look like this after add this
[image]

Comment: This is not I want, I want to have simple list as I shared in screen shot, I just want inside that list a close button to close the list